# Linux Map many internal IPs to one external IP

Tags: linux, networking, port, centos6

I have one Linux machine with many services which needed to be accessed from outside users, each service has one port, how can i make all these service be accessible by one external public IP?

Thank you.

Comment: How come there are multiple "internal" IPs on your (one) Linux machine?  What exactly do you mean by "internal"?

Comment: Sorry a little bit confusing, few VMs on Linux server machine and each using Internal IP which wanna each VM service accessible from outside via one public IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this description ...

> A few VMs on Linux server machine and each using Internal IP which wanna each VM service accessible from outside via one public IP.

The solution is to set up the linux server (running the hypervisor) to use iptables, and then configure iptables to forward connection requests to specific ports on the external IP through to some port on the appropriate internal IP.

Here's a more detailed description:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables

There many other relevant sources if you Google for "iptables port forwarding".

Answer (score -2):

On your router you will need to enable port forwarding or NAT. For each internal port on your Linux Machine, you will create a port forwarding to the name port number and IP address of the Linux Machine on the router.

For example, if you want outside users to connect to the Linux Machine with IP address 192.168.1.20 via port 80 (web), then on the router you will create a port forward that opens the external port 80 and forwards this to IP Address 192.168.1.20 on port 80 as well. So if someone from the outside wanted to connect to the Linux Machine, they would use your PUBLIC IP Address using port 80.

You don't always have to match the outside port with the internal port but it does make it easier to setup and for applications to recognise ie web browsers that use port 80 by default.